# ansible: how to restart auditd service on centos 7 get error about dependency

Tags: ansible, centos7, systemctl

In my playbook, i have a task to update audit.rules and then notify a handler which should restart the auditd service.

```
task:
  - name:  6.6.7 - audit rules configuration
    template: src=X/ansible/templates/auditd_rules.j2
              dest=/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules
              backup=yes
              owner=root group=root mode=0640
     notify:
   - restart auditd


  handlers:
    - name: restart auditd
      service: name=auditd state=restarted
```

When the playbook runs, the audit rules are updated and a request is made to restart auditd but this fails as below.

```
RUNNING HANDLER [restart auditd] ***********************************************
fatal: [ipX-southeast-2.compute.internal]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to restart service auditd: Failed to restart auditd.service: Operation refused, unit auditd.service may be requested by dependency only.\n"}
```

When i look at the unit definition for auditd, i can see refuseManualStop=yes.  Is this why i cant restart the service?  how does one over come this to pickup the new audit rules?

```
 systemctl cat auditd.service
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service
[Unit]
Description=Security Auditing Service
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Before=sysinit.target shutdown.target
RefuseManualStop=yes
ConditionKernelCommandLine=!audit=0
Documentation=man:auditd(8) https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/auditd -n
## To not use augenrules, copy this file to /etc/systemd/system/auditd.service
## and comment/delete the next line and uncomment the auditctl line.
## NOTE: augenrules expect any rules to be added to /etc/audit/rules.d/
ExecStartPost=-/sbin/augenrules --load
#ExecStartPost=-/sbin/auditctl -R /etc/audit/audit.rules
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
# By default we don't clear the rules on exit. To enable this, uncomment
# the next line after copying the file to /etc/systemd/system/auditd.service
#ExecStopPost=/sbin/auditctl -R /etc/audit/audit-stop.rules

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Change the manual stop to NO and try `sudo service auditd restart`
If this works, then the code will also work.

Comment: `systemctl start auditd` and `systemctl enable auditd` is for version CentOS version7. Follow the link for further help. [link](https://skcave.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/using-audit-on-centos-7/)

Comment: There goes one more nice documentation. [AuditD in CentOS7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-custom-system-audit-rules-on-centos-7)..Hope it Helps you.

Comment: thanks.  I didn't really want to mess with the OS side as they must have implemented for a reason.  I would also need to change this on every host.
it seems standard service commands can call systemctl which works for 
 sudo service auditd restart
Stopping logging:                                          [  OK  ]
Redirecting start to /bin/systemctl start auditd.service
 sudo service auditd stop `code`
Stopping logging:                                          [  OK  ]
sudo service auditd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  auditd.service

Comment: thanks for the pointers, looks like the offical way to restart audit with RHEL7 is to use the standard service command.

The service command is the only way to correctly interact with the auditd daemon. You need to use the service command so that the auid value is properly recorded. You can use the systemctl command only for two actions: enable and status.

changed my handler to call the command module instead and this now works

  `handlers:
    - name: restart auditd
      command: service auditd restart`

Comment: Yes. I second you on this restart part. Accept the answer if it helps you. I will paste it as Answer. :)

Comment: `state=reloaded` is not enough?

Comment: Good point but i dont think this works from my testing.  auditd man page states that reload reloads the auditd.conf file.  When i reload, this does not update the rules config, when i restart the config is updated.

thanks for the suggestion thou.

Comment: This question really shouldn't be about Ansible. That just adds a layer of obfuscation without really adding much value. It is strictly an OS issue (or rather, an auditd issue). Once it is resolved at the OS level, the solution within Ansible follows automatically.

Comment: This question promoted discussion and collaboration.  This was an initial investigation into the issue and through this, it came to light that others have asked similar questions and links/discssions were provided about issues at the OS level.  All investigation start someone, see no issue with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restarting auditd service gives dependency error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183536/restarting-auditd-service-gives-dependency-error)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been explored, discussed, and resolved (mostly) in the [Red Hat Bugzilla #1026648](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1026648) and [Anisble Issue # 22171 (github)](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22171) reports.

**Resolution**

- Use the ansible `service` module parameter `use=service` to force execution of the `/sbin/service` utility instead of the gathered-fact value of `systemd` (which invokes `/sbin/systemctl`) like this:

  - `- service: name=auditd state=restarted use=service`
- [Example playbook (pastebin.com)](https://pastebin.com/PjZd77AL)

**Workaround:**

- Use the ansible `command` module to explicitly run the service executable like this:

  - `- command: /sbin/service auditd restart`

*Analysis - root cause:*

> - This is an issue created by upstream packaging of auditd.service unit. It will not start/stop/restart when acted upon by `systemctl`, apparently [by design](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-starting_the_audit_service).
> - It is further compounded by the Ansible service control function, which uses the preferred method identified when system facts are gathered and "ansible_service_mgr" returns "systemd". This is regardless of the actual module used to manage the service.unit.
> - RHEL dev team may fix if considered a problem in upcoming updates (ERRATA)
> - Ansible dev team has offered a workaround and (as of 2.2) updated the `service` module with the `use` parameter.

Comment: It seems that the `use` parameter doesn't work. The ansible reports that the restart task ran, but `systemctl status auditd` shows that the service wasn't restarted. This is with ansible 2.7 on CentOS 7.6.

Comment: @orodbhen Not surprising. The pace of change with Ansible means often that something we know works one month may be out-dated just a few minor versions later.

Comment: This is in fact pretty much the official RedHat-endorsed solution. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2664811 (RH account required for the link) : stop the service with /bin/service, then start it with systemctl.

Comment: It seems that the issue pointed out by @orodbhen can be resolved by using the command workaround rather than `use`.

Comment: Reported bug: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/80142

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is quit late for the answer, but if anyone else is facing the same problem, you can import the new rules for `auditd` with this command :

```
auditctl -R /path/to_your_rules_file
```

So, no need to restart `auditd.service` to import new rules

Comment: I've removed your question from your answer. The answer can certainly stay, but for questions you have to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: No problem, I've posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214714/overwritten-auditd-rules-in-pci-dss-environement

Answer (score 2):

I would validate the auditd service reloading correctly as even using the command module with the command you specified will not work or behave in the manner you would expect it to;

Confirm via

```
service auditd status
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-starting_the_audit_service.html

Try instead

```
service auditd condrestart
```

:)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input.  This is working fine with the command i posted.  The rules are loaded after a normal restart

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the parameter refuseManualStop, it's there to keep you system secure. What you could do instead, after creating new rules, reboot the host, wait for it, then continue with you playbook.

Playbook example:

```
- name: Create new rules file
  copy:
    src: 01-personalized.rules
    dest: /etc/audit/rules.d/01-personalized.rules
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0600
  register: result

- name: Reboot server
  shell: "sleep 5 && reboot"
  async: 1
  poll: 0
  when: result is changed

- name: Wait for server to become available
  wait_for_connection:
    delay: 60
    sleep: 5
    timeout: 300
  when: result is changed
```

Comment: RedHat explains the rationale here (behind a login wall): https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2664811 . The auditd maintainers did it because the kernel treats auditd specially. If you send a kill signal to auditd, it first sends the credentials of the process that sent the kill signal to auditd for logging, but with systemd, that is always PID 1. They didn't want that logged (probably because it would be confusing), so they prevented systemd from restarting auditd.

Answer (score -4):

Change the manual stop to NO and try

> sudo service auditd restart

If this works, then the code will also work

> systemctl start auditd

and

> systemctl enable auditd

is for version CentOS version7. 
Follow the links for further help.

[Link](https://skcave.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/using-audit-on-centos-7/)

[Auditd in CentOS7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-custom-system-audit-rules-on-centos-7)

Comment: Changing the distribution baseline security controls on the audit system is probably not the best option for production systems. This may indeed resolve the problem, but its a bit of a kluge that may create vulnerabilities in the security posture of the system.

Comment: @0xSheepdog: Well, even the OP is aware of it and that's why the answer been accepted. If vulnerability is a concern, then that should be raised by OP, isnt it ? Also, mitigation of enabling auditd vulnerabilities can be further taken care too.