# Restarting auditd service gives dependency error

Tags: docker, audit-logging

I am trying to configure auditing for docker daemon as follows:

Add the line below to the `/etc/audit/audit.rules` file:

```
-w /usr/bin/dockerd -k docker
```

Then, restart the audit daemon using the following command:

```
service auditd restart
```

This gives the following error:

```
Failed to restart auditd.service: Operation refused, unit auditd.service may be requested by dependency only.
```

Using `systemctl` also doesn't work. Is there a workaround or a fix for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating `RefuseManualStop` to no in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service`

```
RefuseManualStop=no
```

Then reload the daemon as follows:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably 2 years too late but for anyone facing the same on redhat 7. Run;

```
service auditd condrestart|try-restart
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-starting_the_audit_service

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution [here](https://systemd-devel.freedesktop.narkive.com/9RzEJTWh/auditd-service-and-refusemanualstop). The method to use is

```
sudo systemctl kill auditd
sudo systemctl start auditd
```